# Karma + Jasmine: Usage of constant like objects

Tags: angularjs, coding-style, jasmine, karma-runner

**In short**: I like to put hard-coded values into a separate file and use them from multiple test specs.

**In detail**: I’m doing the AngularJS tutorial but try to write cleaner code. In [step 5](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), they introduce hard-coded strings like `"Nexus S"`. I like to put such hard-coded strings into a separate file, for example:

```
var TestConstants = function() {
    this.NEXUS_S = 'Nexus S';
};
module.exports = new TestConstants();
```

This is working fine for the protractor tests in the following way:

```
var constants = require('../ test-constants.js');
//…
expect(…).toEqual(constants.NEXUS_S);
```

But it is not working for the unit tests (`require(…)` is not available). I tried to add the file to the `karma.conf` but still can’t reference it.

How can I reference the file in a similar fashion to the e2e protractor tests?
OR: What is best practice to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the file in the files list in Karma as first one.

Change it to the following:

```
// Wrap it in a function to not pollute the global namespace
(function(){

  var TestConstants = function() {
    this.NEXUS_S = 'Nexus S';
  };

  // get the instance you want to export
  var constants = new TestConstants();

  // if module.export is available ( NodeJS? ) go for it,
  // otherwise append it to the global object
  if (module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = constants;
  } else {
    window.constants = constants;
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, I can directly reference it in the karma tests (e.g. 'constants.NEXUS_S') and in the protractor tests as mentioned above.